# Detect iPhone/iPad and change CSS file

Tags: javascript, iphone, css

I don't know whether I should be here or not.

But I'm trying to make a website to detect on which device I am (iPhone/iPad)
and change the CSS-file I'm using.
I'm using this code:

```
function iCheck() {
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../misc/iphone.css' />");
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../misc/iphone.css' />");
}

}
```

but this gives me a blank page with nothing on it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only call `document.write` while the page is rendering (directly in `<script>` blocks).

If you call it after the page finishes loading, it will replace the entire page.

To fix your issue, you can either run your code directly in the `<head>` tag or replace `document.write` with DOM manipulation (`createElement` and `appendChild`) to add a `<link>` tag to the `<head>`.